# Printing to a label (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift

I have some text printing to the console. But I want the text to be printed to a label on the viewcontroller.   I just have some simple code "print(ab)". How should i get it to print to the label?

Comment: Create an `IBOutlet`, connect it to your label then `myLabel.text = "abc"`

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UILabel`?

Comment: where should i put that?  In the viewcontroller, under the "print"?  Or delete the print and put that in ?

Answer (score 2):

> Create new Label on your ViewController with storyboard and Proper alignment/size so it is visible properly and can able to show full text message with proper length, press ctrl and drag it that line to the view controller.Then it pops up a box and mark it as a action and give a name to that Label “yourMessageLabel”

Then it automatically create code like

```
 @IBOutlet weak var yourMessageLabel: UILabel!
var yourMessageText = “Message to be display on Console and View”

override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()

 // do other stuff

 // assign message text to Label to be display on your View

 self.yourMessageLabel.text = (self.yourMessageText as? String)

// print message on console

 print(self.yourMessageText)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to go through [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html). However, this is the programmatic way of adding a label and text on it:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
  super.viewDidLoad()
  var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(<Your_Frame>))
  label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
  label.text = "Your label text" // This is what you are interested in
  self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

If you are working in storyboard then follow the suggestion by Zoff.

Comment: How should I get whats printing in the console to that label? label.text = "jv"

Comment: jv would be the text that is getting printed into the console.  But the text part of a void that is being updated and changed.

Comment: Yes. ` label.text = "jv"` should just work. If label text is being over written by something else then check your implementation... follow the code wherever your `UILabel` is being used including storyboard. Some or the other place you get it overwritten. Better to search for the latest text on your Label in your entire codebase and find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to you storyboard, drag & drop a button.
2. Double click your view controller.Then your view controller open up in a separate window.
3. Then Go to the Storyboard, press ctrl and drag it that line to the view controller.Then it pops up a box and mark it as a action and give a name to that button
4. Then it automatically create code like

   ```
     @IBAction func yourButtonName(sender: AnyObject) { }
   ```
5. Then edit it as this

   ```
     @IBAction func yourButtonName(sender: AnyObject) { 

       yourButtonName.text = "jv"

     }
   ```